# : GitHub Actions: workflow_dispatch event triggers automatically on pull_request opened

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm facing an issue with GitHub Actions where the `workflow_dispatch` event trigger, combined with the `pull_request` event, does not wait for manual actions and triggers automatically upon pull request opening.

Here's a simplified version of my workflow configuration:

```
name: Manual Workflow on PR
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      #...
```

According to the GitHub Actions documentation, the `workflow_dispatch` event should allow manual triggering of the workflow. However, in my case, the workflow always starts automatically when a new pull request is opened, regardless of manual triggering.

I have verified that the indentation of the workflow file is correct, and I have committed and pushed the latest version of the file to the repository. Despite these checks, the workflow fails to wait for manual interaction.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the `workflow_dispatch` event is not waiting for manual actions and how to make it trigger manually as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workflows trigger according to the `on` configuration, if **ANY** of the informed condition is met.

[Documentation: Events that trigger workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows)

In your case with the following configuration:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
  workflow_dispatch:
```

You are actually allowing the workflow to trigger if one of two conditions is met:

1. A Pull Request is opened: [Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request)
2. The workflow is triggered manually (through the GitHub API, GitHub UI or Github CLI): [Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch)

If you just want to trigger the workflow manually, you should only keep the `workflow_dispatch` configuration:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
```

For more informations, you can also check [how to manually trigger workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow) on the documentation.

*Note that there is also a [manual approval for deployments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments) configuration for GitHub Actions, which requires a reviewer approval during a workflow run to continue its process.*

Answer (score 1):

You have configured 2 conditions for action trigger

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
  workflow_dispatch:
```

1. On pull_request Open
2. On workflow_dispatch

you can remove 1 so when any pull request open your workflow didn't run automatically.

```
workflow_dispatch is the keyword you need to run a GitHub Action on demand, without having to push or create a pull request.
```